# linux device driver library not available

Tags: linux-device-driver

hi there is no linux device driver library available on my LInux OS in the folder /usr/src/kernels.Can I add or load it ,if yes how to dothat .i need it for device driver develoment.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need the kernel headers to compile modules/drivers.

On Fedora, you can use the following command

```
yum install kernel-devel
```

On Ubuntu, you can use the following command

```
sudo aptitude install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Or you can also get the entire kernel source/headers from kernel.org